# How do I fix the SQpayment form not generating or passing a nonce to the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, square-connect

I'm attempting to charge cards using square connect for ruby on rails but no nonce is being generated. `nonce =>""` gets passed to my controller.

When I check the Javascript console I realize the error is,

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: requestCardNonce is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

I copy and pasted from [here](https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/blob/master/templates/web-ui/payment-form/basic/sqpaymentform-basic.html) for the `sqpayment` form and from [here](https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/blob/master/templates/web-ui/payment-form/basic/sqpaymentform-basic.js) for the local JS file(entering my `locationID` and `applicationID` correctly. I also copied the appropriate header script.

I've checked for solutions and found similar issues, [Square payment form cannot execute requestCardNonce() to get nonce in Firefox 48.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185727/square-payment-form-cannot-execute-requestcardnonce-to-get-nonce-in-firefox-48).

But these issues were on Firefox browsers (I'm using Chrome) and my code has the event passed to `requestCardNonce(event)` both in my form and local JavaScript file that previous solutions suggest.

```
  <button id="sq-creditcard" class="button-credit-card" onclick="requestCardNonce(event)">Pay</button>

  <input type="hidden" id="card-nonce" name="nonce">
```

In the local JS file the event seems entered properly

```
function requestCardNonce(event) {

  // Don't submit the form until SqPaymentForm returns with a nonce
 event.preventDefault();

  // Request a nonce from the SqPaymentForm object
 paymentForm.requestCardNonce();
}
```

I'd like to get a card nonce so I can begin receiving payments but I can't complete a transaction as long as the requestCardNonce function isn't working. Does anyone have suggestions for how to remedy this?

Comment: So, just to double-check, you are referencing your `sqpaymentform-basic.js` file from your page? Based on the error, it can't see the `requestCardNonce(event)` function. Does the console log show that the form was loaded (in the GitHub example it prints it to the console by default)?

Comment: Yes, I made sure the sqpaymentform-basic.js was referenced. The console does print that the page was loaded.

Comment: Are you referencing sqpaymentform-basic.js before the button click (at the top of the page)? If you create basic stand-alone function (like `test() { alert("test"); }`) and call `test` from the button click instead, does that work, or is also not defined?

Comment: I think I've figured out the reference error. In order to get the JS to work in the DOM I had to envelope it in `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function() {}` This changed the scope of all the functions in the sqpaymentform-basic.js file. The problem is that if I don't include the `document.addEventListener` function the form doesn't load at all.

Comment: Interesting. Try setting the paymentForm field `autoBuild` to false. Then, the only thing you do in the `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"...` would be `sqPaymentForm.build()` to make it load. See info about this here: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/sqpaymentform/how-it-works#single-page-web-applications-customizing-sqpaymentform